Boolean indexing: How to select a specific value to create new column
I have a dataframe which looks like this:
col1 col2 col3
X1   Nan  Nan
foo  bar  baz
foo  bar  baz
X2   Nan  Nan
foo  bar  baz
foo  bar  baz
X3   Nan  Nan
foo  bar  baz
foo  bar  baz


I have filtered to look like this:
m = df.notna()
print(m)

col1 col2 col3
True False False
True True True
True True True
True False False 
True True True
True True True 
True False False 
True True True 
True True True

I need to select the True value in the row with False's, and create a new column with that value.
For example, my resultant df should essentially look like this:
col1 col2 col3 new
foo  bar  baz  X1
foo  bar  baz  X1
foo  bar  baz  X2
foo  bar  baz  X2
foo  bar  baz  X3
foo  bar  baz  X3

I am unsure how to accomplish this with pandas, any suggestions would help

One possible solution is to create the new column based on 'col1' when col2 is null, then ffill the new column and drop unwanted rows with dropna:
df["new"] = df["col1"][df["col2"].isna()]
df["new"] = df["new"].ffill()
df = df.dropna()

  col1 col2 col3 new
1  foo  bar  baz  X1
2  foo  bar  baz  X1
4  foo  bar  baz  X2
5  foo  bar  baz  X2
7  foo  bar  baz  X3
8  foo  bar  baz  X3


A variant to @e-motta's approach using assign, mask and boolean indexing:
m = df['col2'].notna()
out = df[m].assign(new=df['col1'].mask(m).ffill())

If you want to consider "col1" as a header when all other columns are NaN, another option to build the mask would be:
m = df.drop(columns='col1').notna().all(axis=1)

Output:
  col1 col2 col3 new
1  foo  bar  baz  X1
2  foo  bar  baz  X1
4  foo  bar  baz  X2
5  foo  bar  baz  X2
7  foo  bar  baz  X3
8  foo  bar  baz  X3

